# Xamarin - Items not loading or missing from 'Resources' folder in Release only

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

I have developed a `Xamarin.Forms` application using Visual Studio 2019. This targets iOS and Android. I have currently being developing in `Debug` mode.

The application contains many `svg` images which are loaded using the `FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms` plugin as follows:

```
SvgCachedImage imageSearch = new SvgCachedImage
{
    Source = "resource://AppName.Resources.add_red.svg",
    WidthRequest = 25,
};
```

These are all saved under the `AppName/Resources` folder. Each item's properties are as follows:

[image: resource properties]

This works perfectly in the Android simulator, on an Android Phone and also on an iPhone simulator, all in `Debug` mode.

I have now tried to create an Android APK in `Release` mode.

The APK installs onto the Android phone. The application loads without any error, but all of the items in the `Resources` folder are not displayed? All other elements are displayed.

I have tried:

- Code shrinker: None
- Linking: Sdk and User Assemblies

Any ideas or suggestions on what could be causing this?

Versions:

- Xamarin.Essentials (1.3.1)
- Xamarin.Forms (4.3.0.819712-pre2)
- Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms (2.4.11.982)

Comment: Hey Martin! What happens when in Release confug you link none, No code shrinking, use dx compiler?

Comment: @Saamer, that hasn't made a change

Comment: Ok i assume that you had cleaned all cached folders including bin & obj. What's the differences between the Release and Debug configuration files & option settings?

Comment: I have now tried cleaning out bin/obj and a full clean/rebuild, no luck. I've not spotted any obvious differences between `Debug` and `Release` settings.

Comment: Can you share your code? Or a repo with a tinier reproducible version of your problem?

Comment: I might have to try and recreate the problem with a minimal example. I have just recreated it with a direct deployment (i.e.no Archive/APK steps just a direct Run). I'm wondering if the app name is somehow different causing the resource location to be different.

Comment: Hmm I wish i could help you more, all i can think of is some sort of build arguments or perhaps dig into the csproj files to make sure nothings different.

Comment: I know it's possible. Can you share your csproj file vor at least part oft it?

Comment: I am currently rebuilding the whole app using a new project (copying over all cs files from the old). At least the settings will all then be default, I will retest with that. If that fails I will try a simple one page app, if that fails I'll post that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of rummaging around and testing lots of different settings, the solution was to create a completely new solution. I was not able to find a setting that was causing the problem:

1. Create a new Xamarin Forms project.
2. Copy all the original `.cs` and `.xaml` files into the new project folder. Don't copy the `.csproj` files.
3. Add all the resources back into the corresponding folders.

The application was then first tested in `Debug` mode, then in a `Release` emulator. All SVG graphics loaded correctly.

Finally, an Archive and APK was made and tested on an Android phone, all worked perfectly and as expected.

I have absolutely no idea of the actual cause of this problem, but this workaround definitely saved me.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem. In my particular case, i was using Dotfuscator for the xamarin android project in release, and as soon as i disabled this, the menu items started to show.